# Confusing Sentence In Generics And Collection Java

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, language-lawyer

I am reading a book: Java Generics and Collections by maurice and philip.

There is one sentence which i think is wrong:
They have given a code:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src) {
    for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
         dst.set(i, src.get(i));
    } 
}
```

and the sentence is:

> The quizzical phrase ? super T means that the destination list may
>   have elements of any type that is a supertype of T, just as the source
>   list may have elements of any type that is a subtype of T.

AFAIK, the `? super T` means destination list can have elements which are T and its SubType.
I have tested this here:

```
List<? super Dog> tList = new ArrayList<>();
tList.add(new Dog());
tList.add(new HotDog());
```

where `tList.add(new Animal());` is not allowed.
note that `HotDog extends Dog` and `Dog extends Animal`

So if we go according to the book statement, which says tList(Destination list), being `? Super Dog(? super T)`,  can have Animal's instance as it is the Super Type of Dog(T)

Comment: It could be clearer. It actually means that the generic type parameter of `dst` must be a supertype of `T`, in order that it can accept objects of any subtype of `T` being put into it. That's tough to explain clearly in one sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement about `List<? super T>` that it "may have elements of any type that is a supertype of T" is supposed to mean that you first have to choose a definite type `U` that is a supertype of `T`, and then it claims that the list will contain elements of type `U`. This is a very obscure way of explaining it, so let my try to frame it better.

The notation `List<? super Dog>` does not describe one particular list type; it is better understood as a *pattern* against which specific list types are matched. `List<Dog>` and `List<Animal>` match this pattern, but `List<HotDog>` does not.

Now, if you review the above, you'll see that you can safely add objects of type `Dog` to any list that satisfies the given pattern; in fact, the pattern exactly covers *all* list types where this is safe. Further note that "objects of type `Dog`" automatically includes all *subtypes* of `Dog` because that's the essence of the concept "subtype".

This is why we use the `<? super T>` wildcard to generally describe a list that will accept objects of type `T` (it will play the role of a *consumer* of `T`).

The opposite case, that of `<? extends Dog>`, describes all list types that can serve as *producers* of objects of type `Dog`.

All of the above rules are succintly summarized in the PECS principle: "Producer `extends`, consumer `super`."